# How to perform Lua script in Azure Devops pipeline to connect to azure redic cache

Tags: azure-devops, lua, azure-redis-cache

I am trying to connect to my azure redis cache from a azure devops pipeline using azure cli & powershell.
I want to run this lua script on redis cli - but I am having no luck getting there.
It always keeps saying redis-cli not found and we are running our commands on hosted az.

```
EVAL "return redis.call('del', unpack(redis.call('keys', '*<PATTERN>*')))" 0
```

Can someone help on how to purge the redis with pattern from a azure pipeline?

Azure devops pipeline to purge the azure redis cache with a pattern using the EVAL statement.

Comment: updated script - EVAL "return redis.call('del', unpack(redis.call('keys', '\*PATTERN\*')))" 0